# Data structure, tree, n-ary tree, DFS

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, depth-first-search, n-ary-tree

I am solving a simple question based on n-ary tree. Question is simple, finding total number of hand shaking between soldiers where each node of tree represents soldiers. Only ancestors nodes can handshake.

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/trees/binary-and-nary-trees/practice-problems/algorithm/comrades-ii-6/

**It’s the year 2552, the Humans just won a war against a very powerful alien race that had invaded our solar system. The Human army is in celebration mode!**

**The army has n soldiers. The soldiers are numbers from 1 to n. The army has a superiority hierarchy. Every soldier has one immediate superior. The superior of a superior of a soldier is also a superior to that soldier. So, a soldier may have one or more superiors but only one immediate superior.**

**Every soldier has to congratulate every other soldier. For a pair of soldiers if one of them is the superior of the other, they will shake hands. Otherwise, they will bump their fists.**

**You are given the list of immediate superior of all soldiers. Your job is to tell how many handshakes and fist bumps will be there.**

My problem is that I have applied N-ary tree concept using map where `int` is key element storing parent and `vector of int` being its child, and applied DFS but after 2nd iteration my values changes, like:

```
     0                                             0
     |                                             |
     3                                             3
   /   \                                         /   \
  2     4                                       2      0    
 /                         changes to          /        
1                                             1

sample input:
1                                             //  ( test case)
4                                             //  ( number of nodes)
2 3 0 3                                       //  ( parent of node )
```

and due to this my code goes into loop (0 to 3 and then 3 to 0) and hence segmentation fault. I totally screwed up, tried everything but nothing happened.

Here is my code:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
static long long int count1 = 0;

vector<int>::iterator itr;
map<int,vector<int> >tree;

void dfs(map<int,vector<int> > &tree, int node, int height){
    if(tree.find(node) == tree.end() ){
        return ;
    }
    if(tree[node].empty()){
        return ;
    }
    for(itr = tree.at(node).begin(); itr != tree.at(node).end(); itr++){    
        cout<<"node : "<<node <<"   child : "<<*itr<<endl;
        count1 += height;
        dfs(tree,*itr,height+1);
    }
}
int main(){
    int T,N,X;
    cin>>T;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        cin>>N;
        for(int j=1;j<=N;j++){
            cin>>X;
            tree[X].push_back(j);
        }

        dfs(tree,tree[0].front(),1);
        cout<<count1<<endl;
        count1 -= count1;
        tree.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

I wanted to know why this is happening and where is my fault. What is problem in this approach? I know there is many more approaches but why is it failing?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: yup,during recursion when it iterate from parent 3 to its child which is 2 and 4, and for next iteration from 2 as a parent to its child 1 ,it goes right but when it goes back to 3 for next child which is 4 it show 0 as its child not 4 due to which it again goes to 3 the 2 -> 1 and again  0 ->3 ->2 ->1 ; 0 ->3 ->2 ->1, no where 4 like 4 gets ommited

Comment: Well, first off, I would stop using globals. BTW: Your question is off-topic, since it lacks a [mcve]. In particular, you should have removed the need for user input, both as a convenience to others and to rule out that the input is causing the problem.

Comment: i tried nothing happend

Comment: Tried what? Already initially, you said you tried everything. If that was true, only the assumption that there is no deterministic behaviour would rationally justify the effort of continuing.

Comment: i just wanted to know why child of 3 is not showing 4 in function dfs(), so that next time when i implement this type of method ,it would not cause problem.

Comment: Don't use global variables. Then you won't get into trouble with the fact that when you return from  the recursive call to `dfs`, `itr` has been modified causing your loop to detour into limbo.